# Remove Backslash in JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON which is containing backslash characters.

```
"{\"multicast_id\":972977234134833616,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1702805668638456%867f64cc867f64cc\"}]}"
```

I want to remove the backslash. I tried every possible way to remove the backslash. None of it seemed to work. The ways I tried are:

1. JToken.Parse(response).ToString()
2. Regex.Unescape(response)
3. Custom method.

```
 private string RemoveBackslash(string str)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (char c in str) 
            {
                if (c == '\\')
                {
                    char ch = c;
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

4. response = response.Replace("\", "");

Please help me remove the backslash from the JSON string.

I tried every possible ways to eliminate the backslash character. I'm not successful. I tried similar Stackoverflow questions and tried all possible answers. None of them seemed to work.

[This is the screenshot of debugger when I tried response.Replace("\", "")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XGc5.png)

I'm asked to review few other answers. Based on the review, it is now understood that the backslashes were not actually added by .NET. It is visual studio that adds that backslashes. When I tried in Text Visualizer in the debugger, those backslashes were gone. So it's a visual studio thing. The actual string doesn't have that backslash. Brilliant. But here is the issue though. When I actually send that response and view it in the postman, the backslashes does appear. If the original string doesn't contain any backslashes why does it appear in the postman.I want to remove those backslashes that appear in the postman.I need a solution to remove those backslashes.             [The postman image containing the backslashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcsSe.png)

I'm asked to provide a minimal reproducible example. I tried to run the same example given as an answer here.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string jsonString = "{\"multicast_id\":972977234134833616,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1702805668638456%867f64cc867f64cc\"}]}";

        // Method 1: Using JToken.Parse
        string cleanedJson1 = JToken.Parse(jsonString).ToString();

        // Method 2: Using Replace
        string cleanedJson2 = jsonString.Replace("\\", "");

        Console.WriteLine(cleanedJson1);
        Console.WriteLine(cleanedJson2);
    }
```

Because the backslashes were added by the visual studio, to create a minimally reproducible example is really hard.
The above example works in my machine. Meaning the returned json doesn't contain any backslashes. The above example uses JToken.Parse and string.Replace methods. It works when I run it in a console example but doesn't work in my project why? The reason is that who created that backslashes. In the above example the backslashes were part of .NET code. I have given a jsonstring as an input which contain the backslashes. But in my project, those backslashes were added by visual studio. The two methods, JToken.Parse and string.Replace doesn't work when the backslashes were created by visual studio. Based on the link sent to me for review, those backslashes were added by the visual studio but the original string doesn't have it. When I send the string and receive via postman, the backslashes does appear. Here is what I receive via postman.

```
{
"result": "{\"multicast_id\":1184953349068678451,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1702812609911950%867f64cc867f64cc\"}]}",
"error": ""
}
```

If only visual studio adds that backslashes and original string doesn't have it why does postman show up those backslashes.

To recreate this example I want to let visual studio adds those backslashes. If someone guide me a way how to do it, that would be nice.

I was asked a question how I ended up with that json in the first place. Here is the code that generates that json.

```
            public FCMPushNotification SendNotification(string _title, string _message, string priority, string _to)
        {
            FCMPushNotification result = new FCMPushNotification();
            try
            {
                result.Successful = true;
                result.Error = null;
                // var value = message;
                var requestUri = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

                WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
                webRequest.Method = "POST";
                webRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", "AAAA10wXm0Yxxxxxxxxxx"));
             //   webRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", "YOUR_FCM_SENDER_ID"));
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

                var data = new
                {
                    to =  _to, // this is for topic 
                    priority = priority,
                    notification = new
                    {
                        title = _title,
                        body = _message,
                        //icon="myicon"
                    }
                };
                //var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                //var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
                string postbody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data).ToString();
                Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postbody);

                webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                using (Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

                    using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
                    {
                        using (Stream dataStreamResponse = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                            {
                                string sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                                result.Response = sResponseFromServer;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.Successful = false;
                result.Response = null;
                result.Error = ex;
            }
            return result;
        }
[HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public result SendNotification([FromBody] Notification value)
    {
        result rr = new result();
        rr.Result = "Error";
        rr.Error = "";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        string query = "SELECT UserToken FROM AndroidTokens WHERE UserId='" + value.UserId + "'";
        
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        adp.Fill(dt);
        string userToken = string.Empty;

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
            userToken = dr["UserToken"].ToString();
        }
        FCMPushNotification fcmPush = new FCMPushNotification();
        fcmPush = fcmPush.SendNotification(value.Title, value.Message, value.Priority, userToken);
        if (fcmPush.Successful)
        {
            string response = fcmPush.Response; // THIS LINE IS CREATING THE PROBLEM
            string token = response.Replace("\\", "");
            rr.Result = token;
        }
        else
        {
            rr.Error = fcmPush.Error.Message;
        }
        return rr;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you double encoded the data. You could probably just do `response.ToString()`. `JToken.Parse()` should have worked too, you'll need to explain why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: When doing `response.Replace("\", "");`, you need to escape the `\` : `response.Replace("\\", "");`.

Comment: JToken.Parse added \r\n character to the json string. Here is what JToken.Parse gives me. "{\r\n  \"multicast_id\": 8999568032916628070,\r\n  \"success\": 1,\r\n  \"failure\": 0,\r\n  \"canonical_ids\": 0,\r\n  \"results\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"message_id\": \"0:1702807646081854%867f64cc867f64cc\"\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}"

Comment: @Filburt I did response.Replace("\\", ""). It does not work. Oddly enough in the custom method RemoveBackslash, when I keep break points in the lines char ch = c and sb.Append(c), debugger doesn't hit the break point.

Comment: Did you read: [unable to remove the slash "\" in json string in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59488589/unable-to-remove-the-slash-in-json-string-in-c-sharp) ?>

Comment: _Where_ do you "have" that string? And why does the current form pose a problem to you?

Comment: _"None of them seemed to work."_ - define "work". I am suspecting either you are doing something wrong when applying the solutions or your base assumption that you actually have the problem that those are solving is false.

Comment: `This is the screenshot of debugger` - please read the answer in the duplicate question. Or in any other (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466227/11683, https://stackoverflow.com/a/15383815/11683, others).

Comment: @GSerg I totally agree with you. Dot net doesn't add that backslashes. It is visual studio that adds that backslashes. The link pointed out by you asks me to try in TextVisualizer. When I tried in Text Visualizer the backslashes were gone. Brilliant. So it is a visual studio thing. Here is the issue though. When I send the response and view it in the postman, the backslashes does appear. If the ACTUAL string doesn't have that backslashes why does it appear in the post man? I wast to remove those backslashes.

Comment: If you'd post a [mcve] rather than just a single method, we could probably tell you. It would help if you'd post what you see in Postman as text rather than as an image, too.

Comment: "...visual studio that adds that backslashes. " No, Visual Studio **shows** backslashes to make clear that the double quote after it is not the end of the string.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have modified the question. Please review. I also added the postman response as a text

Comment: @Luuk I agree visual studio shows up those backslashes to make it clear that the double quote after it is not end of the string. But problem comes when those backslashes were not removable. Even JToken.Parse and string.Replace were not able to remove those backslashes. When I send that string and receive via postman, the backslash does appear there. I want a way to remove those backslashes

Comment: Your repro is just a console app though - is that actually representative of how you're getting data back to Postman? Fundamentally we have no context for how you've ended up with this JSON in the first place. To my mind the problem isn't actually that you've got more backslashes - it's that I suspect you expect the value of `result` to be an object, but it's actually a string. Without more context, we're not going to be able to understand how you've got that.

Comment: Suppose you have: `string jsonString = "{\"data\": \"test\" }";`. How long is the string `jsonString` ?    (Answer  [see this code](https://onlinegdb.com/VYotEjNZZT))  (its `17`, not 21, or anything else.... )

Comment: @JonSkeet I have added the code which explains how I ended up with that JSON.

Comment: So which part of what you've shown us is from `tReader.ReadToEnd()`? (It would really, really help if you'd just explain the full context. Getting information shouldn't be like getting blood out of a stone. Please read https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints .)

Comment: @JonSkeet string sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                                result.Response = sResponseFromServer; This is the line that generates that json which contain those backslashes

Comment: Except it *doesn't* contain backslashes. At this point I give up: there's still too much ambiguity in what you're trying to do, and you're still talking about backslashes even though you know that's only how VS is displaying things. I strongly suspect all you *actually* need to do is change to `result.Response = JObject.Parse(sResponseFromServer);` or something like that, but it's just guesswork because you keep feeding *one tiny scrap* of information instead of taking a step back. This will be my last comment.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a JSON string that includes escaped backslashes, and you want to remove those backslashes to get a clean JSON string, you can follow these steps in C#:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string jsonString = "{\"multicast_id\":972977234134833616,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1702805668638456%867f64cc867f64cc\"}]}";

        // Method 1: Using JToken.Parse
        string cleanedJson1 = JToken.Parse(jsonString).ToString();

        // Method 2: Using Replace
        string cleanedJson2 = jsonString.Replace("\\", "");

        Console.WriteLine(cleanedJson1);
        Console.WriteLine(cleanedJson2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Method 1 JToken.Parse adds \r\n characters to the string. Method 2 doesn't work. Here is what I got after applying Method 2:  "{\"multicast_id\":4551690448457109459,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1702810247864030%867f64cc867f64cc\"}]}"